# Cannot run the script through Brownie 'deploy.py'

Tags: python, brownie, ganache-cli

I've been following the amazing tutorial on Blockchain/Python/Solidity and I'm stuck on the first steps of using Brownie.
I'm operating on Windows 10, I have pipx, yarn and ganache-cli installed as well as brownie.

When trying to run the script from the newly created file Deploy.py, which only has `def main(): print ("hello!")` . And here is what the terminal returns when running  `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`  :

```
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\brownie_simple_storage> brownie run scripts/deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
   importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
   network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
   rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 75, in launch
   self.process = self.backend.launch(cmd, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 73, in launch
   return psutil.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=out, stderr=out)
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 1312, in __init__
   self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Program, line line, in in
   self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
 File "C:\Program, line line, in in
   hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\brownie_simple_storage>
```

I was running Python 3.10 but Brownie wouldn't get installed. After downgraded to Python 3.9, I could use Brownie. I've tried relocating Brownie's files, removing everything and reinstalling it all, didn't help.

Other thing to note, the message **"INFO: Could not find files for the give pattern(s)**" shows up every time I run a file in the terminal, even when the code gets executed perfectly.

I also cannot understand why the script goes from using files from "C:\Users\chret..." to "C:\Program".

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

UPDATE - after updating Node.js, ganache-cli does appear to have been installed successfully (before, neither the command line nor VSC would show me the version installed through yarn, now they do) but now, when trying to run deploy.py, here is the result:

```
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\brownie_simple_storage> brownie run scripts/deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
   importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
   network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
   rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
 File "C:\Users\chret\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 93, in launch
   raise RPCProcessError(cmd, uri)
RPCProcessError: Unable to launch local RPC client.
Command: ganache-cli
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

The list of networks is as follows :

```
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\brownie_simple_storage\scripts> brownie networks list
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

The following networks are declared:

Ethereum
 ├─Mainnet (Infura): mainnet
 ├─Ropsten (Infura): ropsten
 ├─Rinkeby (Infura): rinkeby
 ├─Goerli (Infura): goerli
 └─Kovan (Infura): kovan

Ethereum Classic
 ├─Mainnet: etc
 └─Kotti: kotti

Arbitrum
 └─Mainnet: arbitrum-main

Avalanche
 ├─Mainnet: avax-main
 └─Testnet: avax-test

Binance Smart Chain
 ├─Testnet: bsc-test
 └─Mainnet: bsc-main

Fantom Opera
 ├─Testnet: ftm-test
 └─Mainnet: ftm-main

Harmony
 └─Mainnet (Shard 0): harmony-main

Polygon
 ├─Mainnet (Infura): polygon-main
 └─Mumbai Testnet (Infura): polygon-test

XDai
 ├─Mainnet: xdai-main
 └─Testnet: xdai-test

Development
 ├─Ganache-CLI: development
 ├─Geth Dev: geth-dev
 ├─Hardhat: hardhat
 ├─Hardhat (Mainnet Fork): hardhat-fork
 ├─Ganache-CLI (Mainnet Fork): mainnet-fork
 ├─Ganache-CLI (BSC-Mainnet Fork): bsc-main-fork
 ├─Ganache-CLI (FTM-Mainnet Fork): ftm-main-fork
 ├─Ganache-CLI (Polygon-Mainnet Fork): polygon-main-fork
 ├─Ganache-CLI (XDai-Mainnet Fork): xdai-main-fork
 └─Ganache-CLI (Avax-Mainnet Fork): avax-main-fork
```

Comment: Answer is here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/103490/57451

Comment: Almost there! I've updated Node.js to the version 17.1.0, now the error message is only 4 lines short and ends up with ` RPCProcessError: Unable to launch local RPC client.
Command: ganache-cli`

Comment: So odd that it's using `ganache-cli.cmd`... it should just be `ganache-cli`... perhaps  you changed something in `brownie networks list`

Comment: I have not changed anything, I didn't even know it was possible. Could you point me to an example of what the list of networks is supposed to look like?

Comment: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html?highlight=networks#networks

Comment: I think you should uninstall and reinstall

Comment: Alright, I've deleted everything down to Python and reinstalled everything. The error message is still the same, I really have no idea what to do ...

Comment: so odd... perhaps this helps? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/110967/57451

Comment: unfortunately, I had followed the same steps (by the way, in that post, NickS also had ganache-cli.cmd running, I'm wondering if that was still the case after updating NodeJS?) and the error message comes back at me once more. I'll have access to another computer this weekend, I'll see if the problem occurs as well. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Hi Patrick, so I ended up cleaning my computer from all coding-related programs (I found out I had missed a few folders before), reinstalled VSC, Python, NodeJS, pipx, yarn, ganache-cli and brownie, and now it seems to be working, apart from the compiler, brownie didn't compile my SimpleStorage.sol file, but I'm looking at the issue right now, probably I forgot to install the proper compiler

Comment: glad you got it!!! So weird it took so many step :(

Comment: well, I'm kinda glad you think it's weird, that means I shouldn't get into that much trouble in the future...? :D Thanks again for the amazing work you do with those tutorials!!!