# getting file not found error while running brownie deploy.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, brownie, solidity-0.6.x

```
PS E:\brownie_simplestorage> brownie run scripts/deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimplestorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 43, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 75, in launch
    self.process = self.backend.launch(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 73, in launch
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 1312, in __init__
    self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Hi KamalShah! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! It seems ganache isn't installed or it isn't available in the PATH.

Comment: Does this answer it? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103489/brownie-cannot-locate-deploy-py-script

Comment: I have installed ganache-cli
but how to put it on the path?