# Why does `brownie run <script>` fail with FileNotFoundError even though the script does exist?

Tags: nodejs, ganache, brownie, windows

I have been trying to run a python "Hello" code using
`brownie run scripts/deploy.py`

I am obtaining the following output:

```
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum


Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 
10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 75, in launch        
    self.process = self.backend.launch(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 73, in launch
    return psutil.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=out, stderr=out)
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 1312, in __init__
    self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\91827\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

However, the file is there in the scripts directory.

Answer (score 0):

This might be redundant. I followed -> [Brownie cannot locate deploy.py script](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103489/brownie-cannot-locate-deploy-py-script)

Steps I followed to run brownie if file not found:

1. Uninstall Node from PC.
2. Reinstall with an updated version. (New version - 16.13.1, as of today) It works. I had an outdated version previously!

It should work now!